# prevent outputcache if request contains specific header-info

Tags: c#, asp.net, outputcache

I have an webapplication (IIS7, .Net4.5, C# & webforms) and output cache is activated.

The output cache is working well except for certain requests containing specific header info I don't want to hit already output cached content i.e request has to hit application business code pageload etc. 
For current request with specific header info I don't want to generate new outputcached content, but output cache should work for 'normal requests' not containing specific header info.

currently  if I use VaryByHeaders an outputcached version of current page will be created. If its a lot of web-trafic it can be a memory-intensive solution and that does not work for me for current solution.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [HttpCachePolicy.AddValidationCallback Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.addvalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The AddValidationCallback method provides a mechanism to check the
>   response programmatically in the cache before the response is returned
>   to the client by the output cache.
>
> Before the response is served from the Web server cache, all
>   registered handlers are queried to ensure resource validity. If any
>   handler sets a flag indicating that the cached response is not valid,
>   the entry is marked as not valid and expelled from the cache. In this
>   case, as well as when any handler indicates that the cached response
>   should be ignored for this request, the request is then handled as if
>   it were a cache miss.
>
> AddValidationCallback is introduced in the .NET Framework version 3.5.

in your site base page add:

```
public void Page_Load()
{
  Response.Cache.AddValidationCallback(new HttpCacheValidateHandler(ValidateCache), null);
}

public static void ValidateCache(HttpContext context, Object data, ref HttpValidationStatus status) 
{
    validationstatus = context.Request.Headers["myheaders"]=="nocache" ? HttpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest : HttpValidationStatus.Valid;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. But if I'm not "allowed" to add an output cache directive in my page(?). For example if visitor should be able to visit all pages (not a specific one) in current web application then I dont want to put output cache directive in my masterpage. I would like to use web.config settings and achieve this without page directive... is this possible in some way?

Comment: @user3154653 not from webconfig. you can only disable all output cache for the site

Comment: I mean if the site is configured by 'config' (not page directive) to use outputcache is it possible for specific request containing specific header info  for all pages to: 1) dont use outputcache 2) dont generate outputcached content for current page without using outputcache directive in page and outputcache setting varybyheaders  ? i.e can I programmaticly override in runtime to not use outputcache and that current request dont create outputcached content    Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3154653 try this solution. is perfect for your case